# How to set visible border to Gtk Image

Tags: gtk

I am having GtkImage to which i want to set visible border like a frame...
so when ever i set any image it will come with default border/frame, which will look good. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way is to put the image into GtkFrame widget.